# Selenium FirefoxDriver errors MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE already been added in dictionary

Tags: c#, firefox, windows-7, selenium, webdriver

After updating Firefox, Selenium IDE and after a reboot, started getting this error in this C# Selenium Test code:

This C# line:

```
WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Errors off with this error message:

- **Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE  Key being added:
  MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE**

Software used:

- Selenium WebDriver version 2.28   Runtime Version v4.0.30319 Visual Studio
- Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft.NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 7
- Firefox 17.0.2 with Selenium IDE 1.10 and Firebug 1.11.1

For a workaround, the following was done:

1. Deleted the Windows 7 Environment variable: MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE 1
2. Rebooted Computer
3. Reran C# Selenium Tests and all worked fine.

I'm not sure how this affects Firefox, but right now everything is working (Firefox works and  C# Selenium Tests work).

Is there another alternative?  Is this an issue with Selenium Webdriver? Firefox?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the WebDriver .NET bindings. Upon construction, the FirefoxDriver tries to add required environment variables to the environment for the Firefox process without regard to whether they are already present. This has been fixed in current sources, and should be available in the next binary release of the .NET bindings. And no, there is no set timeframe for that release, nor would I be able to speculate on one.

Comment: Thanks.. Is the workaround that I used acceptable?  or what do you recommend for a workaround (other than downloading the source and a creating binary).

Comment: The workaround you used should be fine. I don't know what it was that added that variable to your machine's environment, but simply removing it should be okay.